# Storing dictionaries in an array

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have dictionaries which wanted to store them in an array. There is an error when adding the dictionary in an array.

The expected output should be something similar to this.

```
 [{"Name": "A1", "ID": "B1", "Device": "C1"}, {"Name": "A2", "ID": "B2", "Device": "C2"}, {"Name": "A3", "ID": "B3", "Device": "C3"}, ...]
```

Error Code:

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

```
Dim RowDict as Scripting.Dictionary
Dim RowList() as Variant

TotalRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim RowList(0)

for i = 0 to TotalRow
    Set RowDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    RowDict.Add Key:="Name", Item:=SourceWS.Cells(i, 3)
    RowDict.Add Key:="ID", Item:=SourceWS.Cells(i, 4)
    RowDict.Add Key:="Device", Item:=SourceWS.Cells(i, 1)
    
    ReDim Preserve RowList(UBound(RowList) + 1)
    RowList(UBound(RowList)) = RowDict <-- Error here
Next i
```

Comment: Are you just trying to copy the values of `RowDict` into an array (RowList)?

Comment: Try using `Set`.

Comment: @Zac you're right. I am trying to copy the values of RowDict into array RowList.

Comment: @Nacorid suggestion is what you need

Comment: Just remember that you are assigning a dictionary object to the elements of the array when using `Set`. So to reference them, you have to do something like this: `RowList(1).Item("Name")` to get the value back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReDim Preserve` not recommended (in terms of Memory handling) when you can calculate/deduce the array dimension(s)... Then, dictionary is an object and you must `Set` each array element.

```
Private Sub testDictionariesArray()
  Dim RowDict As Scripting.Dictionary, TotalRow As Long, i As Long
  Dim RowList As Variant, SourceWS As Worksheet

  Set SourceWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
  TotalRow = SourceWS .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
  
  ReDim RowList(TotalRow)

    For i = 1 To TotalRow
        Set RowDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
        RowDict.aDD key:="Name", Item:=SourceWS.Cells(i, 3)
        RowDict.aDD key:="ID", Item:=SourceWS.Cells(i, 4)
        RowDict.aDD key:="Device", Item:=SourceWS.Cells(i, 1)
        Set RowList(i) = RowDict
    Next i
    Debug.Print RowList(1).count, RowList(1)("Name")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Option Explicit` and declare all of your variables.

Row 0 is not a valid row, so change the for loop.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim RowDict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim RowList() As Variant
Dim TotalRow As Long
Dim SourceWS As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set SourceWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

TotalRow = SourceWS.Cells(SourceWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim RowList(0)

For i = 1 To TotalRow
    Set RowDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    RowDict.Add Key:="Name", Item:=SourceWS.Cells(i, 3)
    RowDict.Add Key:="ID", Item:=SourceWS.Cells(i, 4)
    RowDict.Add Key:="Device", Item:=SourceWS.Cells(i, 1)
    
    ReDim Preserve RowList(UBound(RowList) + 1)
    Set RowList(UBound(RowList)) = RowDict ' added SET because dictionaries are objects
Next

End Sub
```

or if you are trying to get the items:

```
For i = 1 To TotalRow
    Set RowDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    RowDict.Add Key:="Name", Item:=SourceWS.Cells(i, 3)
    RowDict.Add Key:="ID", Item:=SourceWS.Cells(i, 4)
    RowDict.Add Key:="Device", Item:=SourceWS.Cells(i, 1)
    
    ReDim Preserve RowList(UBound(RowList) + 1)
    Debug.Print RowDict.Items(0) ' shows the item being added in the debug window
    RowList(UBound(RowList)) = RowDict.Items(0)
Next i
```

Comment: `You are probably trying to set the item in the dictionary, not the dictionary itself.` - then there's zero purpose in creating these dictionaries on each iteration.